# Why isn't my isEmpty() method reading as empty?

Tags: java

I have made two boxes within the Driver, one with names and the others with numbers.  They randomly choose a name to a number and print it out.  It also prints out if the box of names is empty (true or false) but on the 5th name after it reads out the name it should also read out the box is empty.  Instead, it causes an error because all of the boxes are empty.  What is wrong with my isEmpty method?  Also, can I get it to ignore the error and instead get it to print out 'The box is empty'?

Driver

```
import java.util.*; 

public class DrawTester
{
/** two boxes within drawTester
* box of names (5)
* box of places at a table (5)
*/

public static void main ( String[] args)
{
String code;

Draw<String> myStringBox = new Draw<>();
Draw<Integer> myIntegerBox = new Draw<>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

//scanner to draw when user requests
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Let's draw some names. Press 'd' to draw. ('q' to stop)");
code = scan.nextLine();

if (!code.equals("q"))
{
    if (code.equals("d"))
    {
        myStringBox = new Draw<>("Happy", "Lucky", "Freddy", "Muddy", "Fuddy");
        myIntegerBox = new Draw<>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        for (int index = 0; index < 10 ; index++) {
            String person = myStringBox.drawItem();
            
            int seat = myIntegerBox.drawItem();
            
            System.out.println(String.format("%s will occupy seat %s.",
            person, seat)); 
            
            boolean isEmpty = myStringBox.isEmpty();
            System.out.println("The box is empty: " + isEmpty);
            
            System.out.print("Enter 'd' to make draw. ('q' to stop)");
            code = scan.nextLine();
                if (code.equals("q")){
                    System.out.println("you quit");
                    break;
                }
        } 
    } 
    } System.out.println("You pressed 'q'");
} 
}
```

Draw class

```
import java.util.*;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public class Draw<T>
{
boolean isEmpty = true;

Random random = new Random();

List<T> items;

public Draw(List<T> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public Draw(T...items) {
    this(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items)));
}

public T drawItem() {
    if (items.size() > 0) {
        int index = random.nextInt(items.size());
        return items.remove(index);
    } else return null;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (items.size() <= 0) {
        isEmpty = true;
    } return isEmpty = false;
}

public String toString() {
    return items.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: `return isEmpty = false;` doesn't mean what you think it does. (Also, `isEmpty` really shouldn't be an instance variable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is assigning false to `isEmpty` and thus always returning it as `false`. Change it to something simpler as follows:

```java
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return items.size() == 0;
}
```

Or as suggested below by @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- (thanks for the hint):

```java
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return items.isEmpty();
}
```

---

Regarding your second question, you will need to add an if condition to check if the `myIntegerBox` is also empty before trying to draw an item:

```java
public class DrawTester {
    public static void main ( String[] args)
    {
        String code;

        Draw<String> myStringBox = new Draw<>();
        Draw<Integer> myIntegerBox = new Draw<>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

//scanner to draw when user requests
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Let's draw some names. Press 'd' to draw. ('q' to stop)");
        code = scan.nextLine();

        if (!code.equals("q"))
        {
            if (code.equals("d"))
            {
                myStringBox = new Draw<>("Happy", "Lucky", "Freddy", "Muddy", "Fuddy");
                myIntegerBox = new Draw<>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
                for (int index = 0; index < 10 ; index++) {
                    String person = myStringBox.drawItem();

                    if (!myIntegerBox.isEmpty()) {
                        int seat = myIntegerBox.drawItem();

                        System.out.println(String.format("%s will occupy seat %s.",
                                person, seat));

                        boolean isEmpty = myStringBox.isEmpty();
                        System.out.println("The box is empty: " + isEmpty);

                        System.out.print("Enter 'd' to make draw. ('q' to stop)");
                        code = scan.nextLine();
                        if (code.equals("q")) {
                            System.out.println("you quit");
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("The box is empty");
                    }
                }
            }
        } System.out.println("You pressed 'q'");
    }
}
```

Still, I think there are some things to improve in the code. For example, why a for loop with the condition `index < 10`? Why 10?

Comment: Or even `items.isEmpty()`

Comment: thanks!  that is much cleaner.  I also found that I could have changed                                                                           boolean isEmpty = myStringBox.items.isEmpty();
System.out.println("The box is empty: " + isEmpty);

Comment: I have 10 because I wanted it to go past the number of entries I had in the draw.  I wasn't sure what else to use.

Comment: You could use `while(!myIntegerBox.isEmpty())` instead of the for loop.